# How to synchronize Silverlight clients with WCF?

Tags: silverlight, wcf, client-server, inotifypropertychanged, synchronize

this is probably only some conceptual problem, but I cannot seem to find the ideal solution.

I'd like to create a Silverlight client application that uses WCF to control a third party application via some self written webservice. If there is more than one Silverlight client, all clients should be synchronized, i.e. parameter changes from one client should be propagated to all clients.

I set up a very simple Silverlight GUI that manipulates parameters which are passed to the server (class inherits INotifyPropertyChanged):

```
public double Height
    {
        get { return frameworkElement.Height; }
        set
        {
            if (frameworkElement.Height != value)
            {
                frameworkElement.Height = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Height", value);
            }
        }
    }
```

OnPropertyChanged is responsible for transferring data. The WCF service (duplex net.tcp) maintains a list of all clients and as soon as it receives a data packet (XElement with parameter change description) it forwards this very packet to all clients but the one the packet was received from.

The client receives the package, but now I'm not sure, what's the best way to set the property internally. If I use "Height" (see above) a new change message would be generated and sent to all other clients a.s.o.

Maybe I could use the data field (frameworkElement.Height) itself or a function - but I'm not sure whether there would arise problems with data binding later on. Also I don't want to simply copy parts of the code properties, to prevent bugs with redundant code.

So what would you recommend?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common solution here is to use a boolean to track your current state within OnPropertyChanged.  It can be set to true when a WCF packet is received, and if it's true, you don't rebroadcast.  You then set it to false after setting the property.

When you set the property normally, you'd just leave it false.  This will cause it to broadcast normally when set internally, but not when set via the WCF call.

This option works, but it does require care to get right.  Since you're putting this logic into a single point, it should be fairly straightforward to get correct.

Comment: Whow - really fast response, thanks! I had thought about this solution, but I was afraid there might be problems with multithreading.

Comment: @user564226: There can be issues - though generally, in Silverlight, it's minimal.  You'll need to take care to synchronize correctly, but again, since it's all handled within a single method, it's usually fairly easy to handle.

Comment: @user564226: It'll probably require a single lock to prevent multiple threads from setting that property simultaneously, if you're using multiple threads here.